# d3; attaching multiple svg to div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

Link to the jQuery / d3 code; [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/T3705Mhg)

The problem is this. I have two separate div's, #temp and #cpu. I want to attach a graph to it with statistical information about the CPU load and about the temperature (it's a graph of the previous 100 hours).

It should attach one SVG to one div. What it does now instead is it attaches the CPU thing correctly, but for the temperature, it adds an empty SVG to the #temp div and adds another SVG with the correct information to the CPU div.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning references to the SVGs to the same variable `svga`. After the SVGs have been created, you can only access one of them -- there's no variable for the other one.

You can solve this either by using different variables (e.g. `svga` and `svgb`) or referencing the SVGs explicitly each time through something like `d3.select("#cpu > svg")`.

Comment: Turns out that I forgot the "break;" in the first switch statement

Comment: That would be a problem, too :)